# Ambiguous call on extension method

Tags: c#

I have an extension method on my project that has been working fine:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T value, T low, T high) 
                                                         where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return value.CompareTo(low) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(high) <= 0;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to build my project I get this error:

> Error 1699    The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'BillingFormsApplication.Extensions.IsBetween(double, double,
>   double)' and
>   'BillingFormsApplication.Extensions.IsBetween(double, double,
>   double)'

There is only one `IsBetween` method in the `Extensions` file... AND only one `IsBetween` method in the entire solution.

I tried to clean and rebuild the solution.  Still getting the error.

I could remove the extension and keep going, but it has been quite handy in the past.

**Added for Frederic:**

```
                    if (percentCash.IsBetween(0, 99))
                {
```

I wonder if I cast those numbers to Double if that will fix it.  I'll try that in a minute.  Like:

```
if (percentCash.IsBetween((double)0, (double)99))
```

Comment: Just noticed the method signature was missing "IComparable<T>" after the "where T : " That was a typo on my part when adding the question, but its in the code.

Comment: try commenting out the extension, and see if intellisence is still able to resolve some `IsBetween` method

Comment: Maybe you have a reference to this extension from multiple dlls.

Comment: Can you post the code at the call site?

Comment: Just added for you Frederic.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I had a namespace reference that was incorrect... not sure how that happened.  I cleaned up my extensions class and made sure none of the other namespaces were wrong, and I'm good to go.  Thanks for quick responses by all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely, you are referencing a DLL that has this same extension method defined or you got this defined somewhere else in your code. Try doing a find in files search for `IsBetween` and see if it comes up. If not, look at the DLLs you have referenced and see if this extension doesn't exist in one of those.